# Why is connection to PostgreSQL on Vagrant VM refused?

Tags: postgresql, vagrant

I have two Vagrant VMs, one configured as a web server and the other a database server.  When I try to run a psql command on the web server against my inventory database on the database server, the connection is refused:

```
psql -h db00 -U dsmith -d inventory -p 15432

psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on the host "db00" (192.168.2.101) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 15432?
```

Here is my Vagrantfile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "debian/stretch64"
  config.vm.synced_folder "./shared", "/vagrant", type: "virtualbox"
  ENV['ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH'] = "/Users/dsmith/playbooks/roles-debian9"

  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.hostname = "db00.example.com"
    db.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.2.101"
    db.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 5432, host: 15432
    config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      ansible.playbook = "provision.yml"
      ansible.compatibility_mode = "2.0"
      ansible.become = true
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "web" do |web|
    web.vm.hostname = "web00.example.com"
    web.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.2.102"
    web.ssh.forward_agent = true
    config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      ansible.playbook = "provision.yml"
      ansible.compatibility_mode = "2.0"
      ansible.become = true
    end
  end
end
```

The key line here is the network forwarded_port line.  I think I'm telling Vagrant that if a request comes in to the database server VM on port 5432, forward it to port 15432 on the server itself which is the port I've configured PostgreSQL to listen to on that server.  From my research, I think this is what I'm supposed to do but I'm not sure.

Here is my PostgreSQL configuration file:

```
# /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main'
hba_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf'
ident_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_ident.conf'
external_pid_file = '/var/run/postgresql/9.6-main.pid'
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 15432
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql'
```

Here is my authentication configuration file:

```
# /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
```

From my research, the "listen_addresses" line is important in the postgres config file and the "host all all..." line is important in the hba config file.

Here are the firewall rules running on the database server:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1037:93696]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 ! -i lo -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state NEW -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.2.102/32 -d 192.168.2.101/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 15432 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_INPUT_denied: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_FORWARD_denied: " --log-level 7
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -s 192.168.2.101/32 -d 192.168.2.102/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 5432 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

The important rule is the one that says that anything from 192.168.2.102 (web00) to 192.168.2.101 (db00) on port 15432 is accepted.  But I really don't think the firewall is the problem since I get the same error if I flush all the rules.

What am I doing wrong here?  I've tried to think it through but I'm missing something.